# The importance of writing return

Tags: javascript

In any JavaScript code, Is it important to write `return` at the end of the function? And would that affect the performance of the website?

Comment: It's quite important when you want your function to return a useful value. If not, then `return undefined;` is implicit and there's no performance difference.

Comment: @Pointy How important exactly? i usually use JS to write HTML codes or data-sets, Does that require `return`?

Comment: Do you know what the `return` statement means? If you invoke a function to compute some result, and you expect the result to be available in the calling environment, then `return` is a critical part of that.

Comment: @Pointy actually i'm just started learning it again, But i never understood why people always write in at the end of their code.

Comment: If there's nothing to return at the end, it makes absolutely no difference if you write it or not. The function returns `undefined` either way. People don't always write it.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious I've never seen anyone doing that, unless they explicitely wanted to return some value.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious they don't always do that. I don't.

Comment: @Pointy I guess its only Youtube courses then, Anyway, i understood your point, please put it in answer.

Comment: Then I'd look for a different course, if they teach such practices. That's something I'd expect from an absolute noob who simply doesn't know better. Not from a "teacher"

Comment: @Thomas though I think the practice would be silly, I would not be surprised if there were serious coding standards out there that insisted upon explicit `return` statements.

Comment: Considering both answers so far, if you have no use for return, the only performance gain you'll have its measured by the number of bytes downloaded by the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain, "naked" `return` at the end of a function, like this:

```
function something(x, y) {
  // code code code
  return;
}
```

does exactly the same thing as the *absence* of such a statement:

```
function something(x, y) {
  // code code code
}
```

Calling either version of `something()` would return `undefined`.

Now, the `return` statement without an expression can be useful when you want to exit the function in some special cases. For example:

```
function somethingElse(object) {
  if (object.importantThing == null)
    return;
  // more code
}
```

A plain `return` like that causes the function to exit immediately, before the rest of the function runs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for using a `return` statement:

1. To end the function before reaching the end.
2. To return a specific value from the function, for use by the callers.

If you don't need to do either of these things, you can omit the `return` statement.  If you reach the end of the function without executing a `return` statement, it's as if the function ended with `return undefined;`.